# Нажатие кнопки в чужом приложении созданном в Qt

Tags: delphi, qt

Есть некоторое приложение, не сильно популярное, но знаю что создано на Qt, для примера можно взять Viber для ПК. Насколько я понимаю программа для отображения кнопок не использует стандартные методы Windows а рисует их сама, поэтому никакими Spy++ не получается отловить где эти кнопки. Как можно в Delphi найти и нажать на любую из кнопок?

Comment: Странный подход. Ты бота делаешь?

Comment: Чтобы нажать кнопку - нужно понять кнопку. А именно понять как она сделана и т.д. В худшем случае - по координатам относительно главного окна.

Comment: Да, почти что бот, но не совсем, по другому никак т.к. весь траф у них по непонятному шифруется. А как понять эту самую кнопку я и спрашиваю, как она сделана по мне так мало где объясняется

Comment: @vip72 как угодно она сделана, без конкретики - гадание на кофейной гуще. Так что развлекайтесь с нажатием по координатам.

Comment: Приложение ДругВокруг

Comment: @vip72 и все сразу бросились бежать его искать, ага. Ссылку хоть на скачивание добавьте...

Comment: https://www.drugvokrug.ru/

Comment: мда, вижу прямо побежали помогать мне активно

Comment: Я думаю, что можно найти как минимум главное (и, видимо, единственное окно) приложения и нажимать кнопки по координатам относительно главного окна, используя функцию [mouse_event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms646260(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Это само собой можно, я хочу передавать проге напрямую клики по кнопкам

Comment: чтобы в винде программно нажать на кнопку надо ей сообщеение отправить. Если кнопка  выполнена не в виде виндового контрола, имеющего свой дескриптор окна, то сообщение отправлять некуда. так что остается эмулировать клик мыши по координатам, как вам написали

Comment: Попробуйте язык Autoit3 [(скачать)](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/), у него а наборе есть программа для просмотра контроллов и окон, может она поможет.

Comment: Я не знаток WinAPI, но почему не попробовать послать окну вашего приложения с помощью SendMessage сообщения WM_LBUTTONDOWN и WM_LBUTTONUP? Эти сообщения посылаются и без явного передвижения курсора в нужную позицию.

Answer (score 2):

А если так?
1. Делаем скриншот окна чужого приложения. Через handle чужого приложения и canvas.
2. Определяем, где какие кнопки, находим их координаты. Не зная, как выглядит интерфейс подсказать не могу, но кнопки отображаются стандартно, по теням их можно отловить
3. Эмулируем нажатие кнопки мыши по нужным координатам.